# How do I move my site from localhost to my domain?

Tags: localhost, xampp

Okay so I'm a complete newbie. 
Things I've done so far: Install xampp, install wordpress, create a dummy site, have a web address I'd like to use.
The problem: My college provides homepages (www.home.uniname.edu/~username) for the students. Now, the files are handles by nextcloud. We are supposed to basically copy our website files on the public_html folder on the nextcloud account. I tried doing this using HTML templates I found online and it works fine. But I can't figure out how to get my wordpress site running. Is this because WordPress files are php? I've searched online and most of them seem to use cpanel but with hosting form godaddy and others. I have no idea how to go about using cpanel.

Tl;dr: Have a college assigned homepage. HTML templates work fine when uploaded to public_html. Made a wordpress site but can't get it online. Need a walk through. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you just follow the steps

(1)install All-in-one-WP-migrate plugin in your local and make a copy of your local site by selecting file in the menu of export.

(2)then on you live server install WordPress and also install all-in-one-wp-migrate plugin and then  import the file you make from local.

it will take up-to 10 minutes depending on your internet connection.
once it finish then login to site with your localhost username and password and go to settings and save permalink 2 times.

now enjoy your local site is live

Answer (score 0):

below blog gives both methods Manual and Plugin wise with proper steps. https://blog.templatetoaster.com/move-wordpress-localhost-to-live-server/

Answer (score 0):

### If your live server has PHP execution:

If you do not wish to use a plugin to migrate your site (I never do,) follow this:

- Dump your database to a .sql file. Use phpmyadmin, Sequel Pro, or whatever other tool you have on hand.
- Import the database into whatever DB server > database your live site will use.
- Change wp-config.php to reflect the settings for the live server
- Upload your entire wordpress directory to the new server/public_html/

This is of course only valid if the server where the files lie, can execute PHP code. If it cannot, then this approach will not work of course.

### If your live server does NOT have PHP execution:

I have a feeling this is the issue you're actually having because afaik, NextCloud is merely a file server in "the cloud" and does not allow PHP execution.

What you can do in this case, is to run an application like Site Sucker, point it to your local site and let it run. It'll essentially save a "hard copy" of your entire site. Then you simply upload those files to NextCloud.